# TypeError: render_template() flask

Tags: python, flask

This is my code and the error appears ad below. i don't know why. help me

---

```
from flask import url_for, session, Flask, request, redirect, render_template

application = Flask(__name__)
application.secret_key = "sadqwwqds"


@application.route("/")
def home():
    if "userID" in session:
        return render_template(userid=session.get("username"), login=True)
    else:
        return render_template(login=False)


@application.route("/login", methods=["get"])
def login():
    pass


@application.route("/logout")
def logout():
    pass
```

application.run(host="0.0.0.0")

---

TypeError: render_template() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template_name_or_list'
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2023 15:28:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

---

```
{% if login == True%}
<meta charset="utf-8">
<h3>login success {{username}}welcome</h3>
<a href = {{ url_for("logout") }}>logout</a>
{%else %}
<form methods = "get" id="login" action={{url_for("login")}}>
    <input type ="id" id ="loginid" name="loginId" placeholder="input">
    <input type="password" id="loginPw" name="loginPw" placeholder="input">
    <button type="submit" class="login">login</button>
</form>
{%endif%}`
```

I tried to modify the HTML code, but it din't work
where's the problem?

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong - you haven't given a template name

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of Flask states that you have to specify `template_name_or_list` (see
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.render_template)
Here you specify only keyword arguments, none of which is the `template_name_or_list`:

```py
@application.route("/")
def home():
    if "userID" in session:
        return render_template(userid=session.get("username"), login=True)
    else:
        return render_template(login=False)
```

Modifying the HTML won't help, pass the template name to `render_template` in your main.py. I don't know your path, neither the name of the template, but with placeholder it looks like this:

```py
return render_template("<PATH_TO_YOUR_TEMPLATE>/<FILENAME>", userid=session.get("username"), login=True)
```